# Can't add data into ViewModel DbSet

Tags: c#, model, asp.net-mvc-5, dbset

```
public ActionResult MojeTeme() 
{
    var db = new Palindrom.Models.Baza1Entities();
    var db1 = new Palindrom.Models.Entities();

    var db2 = new Palindrom.VjuModeli.ProfilKorisnika();

    var naslovi = db.PalindromBaza.Select(m => new Palindrom.VjuModeli.TemeKorisnika { Korisnik = m.Korisnik, ID = m.ID, Naslov = m.Naslov });

    foreach (var red in naslovi)
    {
        if (db2.teme != null)
            db2.teme.Add(red);
    }

    return View(db2);
}
```

I have a problem understanding why this code isn't working.

I have two models that I need some data from that I want to put into a single view model:

```
public class ProfilKorisnika
{
    public DbSet<TemeKorisnika> teme { get; set; }
    public  DbSet<PKorisnika> profil { get; set; }
}
```

I want to focus on just one of these DbSets as I hope it's just a copy and paste afterwards.

`DbSet<TemeKorisnika>` should have no data before the `db2.teme.Add(red)` line.

I made a variable `naslovi` to hold the three columns that I need for that `DbSet<TemeKorisnika>` and I wanted to use a foreach loop to fill the `db2.teme`. Problem is, when I try to load the View, I'm greeted  with a `NullReferenceException` and the Debugger directs me to this line of code: `db2.teme.Add(red)`.

I'm certain that the `red` variable isn't null, nor is the `naslovi` variable.

Through some research, I have been led to believe that `db2.teme` isn't initialized, as a beginner I'm not completely sure I know what that means in this situation, how can it not be initialized if it's a part of the initialized class `ProfilKorisnika` that's instantiated in the `db2` object, am I missing something?

I have been spinning around this way of adding the data for a while and haven't tried anything that doesn't resemble this.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the bulk of the code to this and it works:

```
var naslovi = db.PalindromBaza.Where(m => m.Korisnik == User.Identity.Name);
       
        var ajdijevi = db.PalindromBaza.Where(m => m.Korisnik == User.Identity.Name);

        var profil = db1.AspNetUsers.Select(m => new Palindrom.VjuModeli.PKorisnika {OpisPr = m.OpisProfila,NazivPrSl=m.NazivProfilneSlike ,Korisnik = m.UserName});

        List<Palindrom.VjuModeli.VjuModZaProfil> profilov = new List<Palindrom.VjuModeli.VjuModZaProfil>();
        int i = -1;

        try { 
            ajdijevi.First(); 
            foreach (var red in naslovi)
            {
                i++;
                profilov.Add(new VjuModeli.VjuModZaProfil
                {
                    ID = Convert.ToInt32(ajdijevi.ToArray()[i].ID),
                    Korisnik = profil.First(m => m.Korisnik == User.Identity.Name).Korisnik.ToString(),
                    Naslov = naslovi.ToArray()[i].Naslov.ToString(),
                    OpisPr = profil.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Korisnik == User.Identity.Name).OpisPr.ToString(),
                    NazivPrSl = "img.png"                
                }
               );
            }
        }

        catch { 
            profilov.Add(new VjuModeli.VjuModZaProfil
            {
                Naslov = "nslv",
                ID = 0,
                Korisnik = profil.First(m => m.Korisnik == User.Identity.Name).Korisnik.ToString(),
                OpisPr = profil.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Korisnik == User.Identity.Name).OpisPr.ToString(),
                NazivPrSl = "img.png"
            }
            );
        }
        return View(profilov);
```

I also modified the ViewModel to this:

```
public class VjuModZaProfil
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Korisnik { get; set; }
    public string Naslov { get; set; }
    public string OpisPr { get; set; }
    public string NazivPrSl { get; set; }
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone, if there is something that's nonsensical to anyone about this code, I'd like to clear it up.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**